# Issue with getting value of checkboxes tkinter

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I'm trying to get the value of checkboxes in tkinter so I can have the data from those checkboxes exported into a excel spreadsheet

I've tried having the checkboxes generate iteratively (as they are presently) and making them manually, but no matter what I do, can't get them to give me their values (whether they are checked or not) and it's really stressing me out.

```
def check():
    for movie in movies():
        print(button.get())

Button(moviewindow,text="Check",command=check).pack(anchor=S)
for movie in movies():
            var1 = IntVar() 
            button = Checkbutton(moviewindow,
                        bg=moviewindow_bg,
                        font=("Times",23),
                        onvalue=1,
                        offvalue=0,
                        text=movie.replace("<strong>","").replace("</strong>",""),
                        variable=var1).pack(anchor=W)
```

I expect the code to print either 1 or 0, but I cant get the checkboxes to return their values.

Comment: Is this code top-level or is it called in a function? Your issue is probably related to the fact that after running this code you will have a variable `button`, containing only the last button created when it seems what you wanted to do was to associate a button with each movie in `movies()`. What *does* it print when you run this code? Nothing?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code should give an error but you don't mention an error. It's also not clear if that code is inside a function or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your variables (and possibly, buttons) somewhere. What's happening currently is this:

You create a `Button` that runs the function `check`. Inside `check`, you iterate over movies, and try to get the value from `button`. You should be getting the value from `var1`, but that's not the chief issue here. The main problem is that *`var1` only contains the very last `IntVar` created, so the loop will only repeat the value of the last checkbox you created*.

Without knowing what kind of an object `movie` is, it's hard to say the best way to proceed here. If `movie` is a class object, you could perhaps change its properties. If it's a hashable object, here's what you can do.

Somewhere above your code: Create a dict for association between movies and vars

```py
checkbox_vars = {}
```

Fix `check` to use this dict

```py
def check():
    for movie in movies():
        print(checkbox_vars[movie].get())
```

Within your loop, store the variable in the dict

```py
var1 = IntVar()
# Store the variable in checkbox_vars, for this specific movie
checkbox_vars[movie] = var1
```

This is still a somewhat inelegant way to do it, but it should illustrate how you need to actually create an association between `button`/`var1` and `movie` yourself instead of it being implicit.

Comment: So what do I actually put into the dict? I'm really new to python and this is my first major project for school.

Comment: In this example I've given, you put the IntVar attached to the button (checkbox) in the dict. Then when the button changes the value of that IntVar, check should see the correct value

Comment: Would it be helpful if I provided you with the full code so you know exactly what it is I'm trying to do? Everything I've tried has not worked and I'm getting really stressed out because this project is due tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Use `var1.get()` to get the current value of the checkbox.

To print the value as soon as the check button is updated, use it inside the button's [invoke](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm#Tkinter.Checkbutton.invoke-method) method.

Comment: I've tried this, but it only returns 0, when it SHOULD return a 1 when the checkboxes have been ticked. How do I get it to return 1?